# What's the standard way of add/remove items to/from a Web Component layout?

Tags: javascript, layout, web-component

I'm writing web components using `VueJS` and `vue-custom-element` package. The web component that I'm creating is a layout components containing multiple modules such as *chat*, *userList* and so on. I need to add the ability to add/remove elements from the layout **at runtime**.

How can it be possible?

`<my-layout></my-layout>`

**This is a simple layout. How can I make these buttons work?**

[image]

This is the current layout template:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button>Add new chat module</button>
    <button>Add new users module</button>
    <div id="layout" class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <my-chat></my-chat>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <my-users></my-users>
      </div>
    </div>
    <block :menu="testMenu">Custom block</block>
  </div>
</template>
```

These are possible solutions :

- Calling a method inside the web component. (It's seem that it's not possible!)

  - `document.getElementById("layout").addModule('chat')`
- Sending a configuration JSON as attribute containing the list of requested modules and their 
  count.

  - `<my-layout conf='{"modules":{"chat":{"count":5}}"}'></my-layout>`
- Add a separate `count` attribute for each module.

  - `<my-layout chat-count="5" users-count="2"></my-layout>`

Comment: Vue has an app state, like most frontend frameworks. Layouts/templates are supposed to turn the state into HTML and are updated as soon as the state changes. You never manipulate the DOM directly, and you don't put data or methods in the layout.

Comment: @ChrisG I cannot understand, Maybe I didn't explain my problem. I don't want to manipulate it directly. I wrote the layout component myself and want to add this customization to it

Comment: Yeah, to be honest I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. It does sound like conditional rendering maybe? You say you want to add elements as needed; while the app is running? Or during initial setup? Can you put a [mre] on codesandbox or somewhere that illustrates the issue?

Comment: @ChrisG I want to do it at runtime. I added updated the example image but there is no implemented code for this job.

Comment: Given the question edit you probably want to check the Vue docs for a) list rendering b) conditional rendering. You basically maintain a list of components in the Vue app's state, and make the buttons add to the list.

Comment: You could use dynamic components as documented here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components